# Calculate date difference between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to find difference between two dates.
It simple does not display anything , empty page shown for the date difference.

below is the code that i am using.

```
<?

$sql = $Db1->query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5");

while($row = $Db1->fetch_array($sql)) {

$datetime1 = date("m-d-Y",mktime(0,0,$row['rec'],1,1,1970));
$datetime2 = date("m-d-Y",mktime(0,0,$row['send'],1,1,1970));
echo "$datetime1";
echo "$datetime2";
$diff=date_diff($datetime1,$datetime2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
echo "$diff";


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function

```
$date1 = $row['rec'];
$date2 = $row['send'];
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

Comment: it works but display something like this :
0 years, 0 months, 0 days 0 years, 0 months, 0 days 0 years, 0 months, 0 days 2709 years, 9 months, 22 days 1062 years, 8 months, 19 days

I wanted only the days, :(

Comment: pls post your date format ? date format should be in //2014-12-24//

Comment: Date format is text, this is something i can not change. as its an existing database.

Comment: pls post the  text here ?

Comment: rec: 1407046749  
send:1407235753

Comment: okay fine. its in timestamp format.. you have to convert to date format lke this $date1 = date('Y-m-d', $row['rec']);
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', $row['send']);

Comment: $date1 = date('Y-m-d', $row['rec']); $date2 = date('Y-m-d', $row['send']);
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);

Answer (score 0):

i have created a function that i use you can change it to as per your requirement.
leave date two empty if you want to find difference b/w current date and given date.

```
function dayspassed($dategiven, $dategiven2){
if(empty($dategiven2)){
    $currentdate = date('Y-m-d');  
}else{
    $currentdate = $dategiven2;  
}
  $currentdate = strtotime($currentdate);
  $dategiven = explode(" ", $dategiven);
  $dategiven = $dategiven['0'];
  $yourdate = strtotime($dategiven);
  $datediff = $yourdate - $currentdate;
  return $difference = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

}

Comment: does not show anything again even with this function

Comment: the result from your database show only date or datetime ?
if it is datetime you need to use explode and store only dates in variables then use those variables in that function

Answer (score 0):

I have the following function:

```
function get_date_difference_in_days($timestamp1, $timestamp2) {
    $inputSeconds = abs($timestamp1 - $timestamp2);
    $days = floor($inputSeconds / (24 * 60 * 60));
    return $days;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that date_diff works with datetime objects, and you were passing parameters as a string and not as datetime objects.

Looking at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) clearly states that date_diff is an alias function for DateTime::diff().

So the solution would be:

```
$row = array("rec" => "2014-12-24", "send" => "2014-12-20");

$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $row["rec"]);
$datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $row["send"]);

echo $datetime1->format("Y-m-d");
echo $datetime2->format("Y-m-d");

$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $diff->format("%r%a");
```